# How to define title, description and color in leaflet Draw

Tags: leaflet-draw

I am trying to create a participatory mapping site where users can draw polygons using Leaflet draw.

Just to know how can i create a pop window where users can define a title, description and color of the polygon which they draw **or** after they draw, click on the feature and add a label,description and color?

Comment: Using something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133379/how-to-export-to-all-points-within-leaflet-polygon You could capture the polygon, and getElementByID could capture the text boxes which can be pushed to the GeoJSON but then what? PHP or something to write to the server database? Update scripts if it exists? Not one simple problem but many within the 
'How to'  question.