# How to export to all points within Leaflet polygon?

Tags: polygon, leaflet, export

Is it possible to export all points within a polygon drawn using Leaflet?

(http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/).

Comment: Yes it is, but the implementation depends on what you mean by *export*. Also, do you just want to 'export' a polygon's shape or specifically all of its vertices?

Comment: How can we do the same thing in React-leaflet.

Answer (score 5):

It is simpler than that.

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'polygon') {
        // here you got the polygon points
        var points = layer._latlngs;

        // here you can get it in geojson format
        var geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
   }
   // here you add it to a layer to display it in the map
   drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Although 'export' is very ambiguous, here's a way to console log the drawn polygon as 'geojson' string. Working from [this example](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/), replace the `map.on('draw:created')` callback with the following:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'polygon') {
        // structure the geojson object
        var geojson = {};
        geojson['type'] = 'Feature';
        geojson['geometry'] = {};
        geojson['geometry']['type'] = "Polygon";

        // export the coordinates from the layer
        coordinates = [];
        latlngs = layer.getLatLngs();
        for (var i = 0; i < latlngs.length; i++) {
            coordinates.push([latlngs[i].lng, latlngs[i].lat])
        }

        // push the coordinates to the json geometry
        geojson['geometry']['coordinates'] = [coordinates];

        // Finally, show the poly as a geojson object in the console
        console.log(JSON.stringify(geojson));

    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

From there, depending on what you mean by export, the solution could be as simple as opening your browser console (F12) to copy and save the json string as a geojson file, or as complex as posting the result to a server, and returning the file for download

Comment: Did OP find a solution to original question? Or can @toms elaborate on selecting markers in drawnItems with the polygon geojson.  The solution [provided only returns a geojson of the polygon?

Answer (score -1):

You just need use `layer.getLatLngs();`
Example :
Var coordinates  is your answer in [this jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/x4wz9dL5/11/).

Comment: This is a link only answer, you need to provide more information in the body of the question.